# Force DropDown list SelectMethod at PageLoad

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, selectmethod

I'm developing a little web-form based web application. It uses some DropDownList asp controls. This is the control which I've appended a default empty value **--- seleziona ---**

```
                <asp:DropDownList
                    ID="dropQuestionari"
                    runat="server"
                    SelectMethod="GetQuestionari"
                    AppendDataBoundItems="true"
                    ItemType="Models.Questionario"
                    DataTextField="Questionariointestazione"
                    DataValueField="idQuestionario">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="--- seleziona ---" Value="" Selected="true"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
```

The control uses `SelectMethod` property with `GetQuestionari()` method that retrieves all the items needed to populate the list.

It work fine, but I need to check if the drop-down list is empty (excluding the default item) and change the default object text if so. I tried like this (in code behind):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        //...

        if (dropQuestionari.Items.Count == 1) 
        {
            dropQuestionari.Items[0].Text = "Nessun questionario per l'utente corrente";
            this.confirmButton.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

It seems that the list is not populated at page-load and `dropQuestionari.Items.Count` always returns `1`(obviously it counts only the default item). How can I force the list to be populated in the PageLoad?

Answer (score 0):

You're checking the count when the page ISN'T a post back, meaning it's the first time the page is loaded. If it's the first time, the DDL would not be populated.

Comment: Even trying without `if` condition and setting `AutoPostBack="true"` property on the control it still has the same behavior.

Comment: Are you trying to check the control on the initial visit? Or is this on subsequent postbacks?